# How do I fold 20 bytes into 8 bytes

Tags: byte, folding

1. This is how I currently fold 16 to 8
2. How do I fold 20 bytes into 8 bytes

```
    ac = regs[0] ^ regs[2];
    bd = regs[1] ^ regs[3];
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        fold[i] = (sbyte)(ac & 0xff);
        ac >>= 8;
    }
    for (i = 4; i < 8; i++)
    {
        fold[i] = (sbyte)(bd & 0xff);
        bd >>= 8;
    }

    return fold;
```